# Ansible: How to install RPM packages based on RHEL or OS version?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I use Ansible in order to install RPM packages on RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 Linux machines.

Is it possible to exclude the following packages only for RHEL 7 version? So `yum install libselinux-python` will be performed only on RHEL 7 version and not on RHEL 8 version?

```yaml
- name: install libselinux-python
  yum:
    name: libselinux-python
    state: present
```

Example from RHEL 8

```bash
more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)
```

Example from RHEL 7

```bash
more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 7.6 (Ootpa)
```

Comment: Use Ansible facts: `when: "ansible_distribution_major_version is version('8, '<')"`

Comment: can you post your solution so I can vote if answer is correct

Comment: See in example [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample of a slightly verbose description of a condition using when.

```
- name: install libselinux-python
  yum:
    name: libselinux-python
    state: present
  when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "7"
```

Comment: is it must to add "gather_facts: yes"   after yum ?  or not need ?

Comment: In fact it is not required. By default, Ansible gathers facts at the beginning of each play. So gathering facts is required for this when: condition but need not to add it in your playbook. see [Disabling facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#disabling-facts)